# Serial port data plotter in PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, pyqt

I am rather new in GUI programming and multi-threading apps. It is just a serial port monitor which plot serial data via `pyqtgraph`. There are two curves on the first plot (`a` and `b`) and one curve on the second plot (`c` which is `(a-a_prevous)/(b-b_prevous)`). How can I improve this code in general? I use Python3.5.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
import sys
import serial
import pyqtgraph
import threading
import ui_main
import numpy as np

class GraphPlotter(QtGui.QMainWindow, ui_main.Ui_GraphPlotter):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pyqtgraph.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
        self.a = []
        self.b = []
        self.c = [0]
        self.flag = 'a'
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.plotAB.plotItem.showGrid(True, True, 0.7)
        self.plotC.plotItem.showGrid(True, True, 0.7)
        self.monitor = SerialMonitor()
        self.monitor.bufferUpdated.connect(self.update)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.monitor.start)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.monitor.stop)
        self.clearBufferButton.clicked.connect(self.clear)

    def update(self, msg):
        if self.flag == 'a':
            self.a.append(msg)
            self.flag = 'b'

        elif self.flag == 'b':
            self.b.append(msg)
            c = pyqtgraph.hsvColor(0.2, alpha=.5)
            pen2 = pyqtgraph.mkPen(color=c, width=3)
            try:
                print((self.a[-1] - self.a[-2]), (self.b[-1] - self.b[-2]))
                self.c.append((self.a[-1] - self.a[-2]) / (self.b[-1] - self.b[-2]))
                self.plotC.plot(np.arange(len(self.c)), self.c, pen=pen2, clear=True)
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                print('Division by zero')
                self.c.append(0)
            except IndexError:
                print('C is not ready')
            finally:
                self.flag = 'a'

            for y, pen in [(self.a, (255, 0, 0)), (self.b, (0, 255, 0))]:
                self.plotAB.plot(np.arange(len(y)), y, pen=pen)

    def clear(self):
        self.a = []
        self.b = []
        self.c = [0]

        self.plotAB.clear()
        self.plotC.clear()


class SerialMonitor(QObject):
    bufferUpdated = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super(SerialMonitor, self).__init__()
        self.running = False
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.serial_monitor_thread)

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def serial_monitor_thread(self):
        while self.running is True:
            ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 115200)
            msg = ser.readline()
            if msg:
                try:
                    self.bufferUpdated.emit(int(msg))
                except ValueError:
                    print('Wrong data')
            else:
                pass
            ser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    plot = GraphPlotter()
    plot.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I've edited this code, and now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inheriting from `ui_main.Ui_GraphPlotter`, I would use the [`PyQt4.uic`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#module-PyQt4.uic) module to dynamically load your ui file in the `__init__` method:

```
import os
import pyqtgraph

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import uic

curdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


class GraphPlotter(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi(os.path.join(curdir, 'GraphPlotter.ui'), self)
        pyqtgraph.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
        # ...
```